# What differences are there between 2.5" and 3.5" disks?

Tags: hard-drive

Besides price and size, what difference are there between a 1TB SATA 3.5" and 2.5" HDD?

Are there pro/cons in regards to noise/through put/response time/robustness?

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/understanding-hard-drive-performance,1557.html kind of old but worth a read. I might post a proper answer if no one has by tommorrow.

Comment: I think the only difference is size :) You can't talk about other parameters (noise, response time, power consumption...), because they are not connected to size. There can be a small SSD faster than your current HDD. I would recomend you to look at benchmarks.